# Exists an implementation like SynchronousQueue with capacity?

Tags: java, multithreading, queue

In a Java application reading items from a Socket connection I need (for reasons not further outlined here) the

1. input items to be processed by a single thread so that their order is preserved.
2. input items to be buffered before processing so that new items can be read from the socket while others are still being processed.
3. the reading thread to be blocked as long as the buffer is full

So actually I would like to use a single worker thread to work on buffered items received from the socket. And a fitting queue as buffer between the worker thread and the reader thread which would be a kind of a fair `SynchronousQueue` with a FIFO capacity.

The queue required should behave like an `ArrayBlockingQueue` or `LinkedBlockingQueue` with capacity while not full and similar to a `SynchronousQueue` when full meaning that

1. `put` on the queue will only block the thread if the queue is full
2. `take` on the queue will only block the thread if the queue is empty
3. `take` on a full queue will give the caller the next FIFO element and unblock and inserting the element from the next thread waiting in a `put` operation
4. `put` on the empty queue will either hand over the element to thread waiting in a `poll` operation or insert it

Is there any known implementation like that or do I have to roll out my own?

Comment: How is it different from `ArrayBlockingQueue`?

Comment: Can you clarify how that is different to an `ArrayBlockingQueue`? A ExecutorService with a SynchronousQueue doesn't block if there is no thread available either.

Comment: @PeterLawrey yes you are right! `ThreadPoolExecutor` actually does not use `put` but `offer`. So it seems that it does not make any sense to use a `ThreadPoolExecutor` with a single thread together with a `SynchronousQueue`. I clarified in the text that I have to use my own worker thread to repeatedly `poll` items from the queue.

Comment: @all you are right! I got messed up with the different methods a `BlockingQueue` offers to insert/remove items :/ Seems that is exactly what I need. Anyone who first writes an Answer will get accepted ;)

Comment: As an aside, it's not too difficult to process the bufer objects on multiple threads.  If each gets an incrementing sequence-number before being pushed onto the queue, the output from multiple threads can be resequenced on processing completion.  Needs a container for objects that are awaiting the arrival of earlier objects.

Answer (score 1):

One answer that is not just an attempt to steal points from those posters who suggested an ArrayBlockingQueue :

Two ArrayBlockingQueues. One to act as a 'pool queue' - filled with buffer objects at startup. The other for the processing thread/s to wait on for work.

The socket thread must get a buffer from the pool before loading it with data and queueing it to the processing threads.  The processing threads, after handling the data, must eventually return the 'used' objects back to the pool.  If the pool empties, the socket thread blocks on it until some buffers are returned.

This provides the same flow-control as a bounded processing-queue, but with the added advantage that GC on the buffers is avoided.